# Are there any methods to call ather files in attribute "action"?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm writing a plugin for wordpress and my count.php file doesn't works without calling wp-load.php

```
 <form method="post" onload="MyFunction()" id="WidgetForm" onsubmit="return false;" action=<?php echo plugins_url('/count.php',__FILE__); ?>>
```

Are there any ways to call this count.php that works withaout wp-load.php??

Comment: it will never execute the action because of `onsubmit="return false;"`

Comment: I don't want to go this page,  my count.php fail returns me values.... but it doesn't work without wp-load